# How to download a CSV file from FRED without MATLAB altering it

Tags: matlab, csv, download

In MATLAB, if I use the `fred` and `fetch` functions I get a `1x1 structure` which contains the Data as doubles. For example using

```
url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/';
c = fred(url);
series = 'DEXUSEU';
d = fetch(c,series)
```

Where the output is:

```
d = 

struct with fields:

             Title: ' U.S. / Euro Foreign Exchange Rate'
          SeriesID: ' DEXUSEU'
            Source: ' Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)'
           Release: ' H.10 Foreign Exchange Rates'
SeasonalAdjustment: ' Not Seasonally Adjusted'
         Frequency: ' Daily'
             Units: ' U.S. Dollars to One Euro'
         DateRange: ' 1999-01-04 to 2018-06-15'
       LastUpdated: ' 2018-06-18 3:51 PM CDT'
             Notes: ' Noon buying rates in New York City for cable transfers payable in foreign currencies.'
              Data: [5075×2 double]
```

The problem is that I want to download and save the **original** CSV file from `fred.stlouisfed.org` (which you can download manually on the website). In other words, I want to avoid having to use for example `csvwrite('filename.csv',d.Data)` to recreate a CSV-file (which will not be identical with the CSV-file from FRED), and instead simply download and save the original CSV-file from FRED without MATLAB altering anything.

Comment: Where is the .csv file located at `https://fred.stlouisfed.org/` ?

Comment: hi! you will find it at https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DEXUSEU and then you have to click the 'Download' button in upper right corner

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: yes! the problem is that the link shown for the button is https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DEXUSEU#, which does not get me to the original FRED csv file